# How to apply shock front absorbing boundary condition in LAMMPS

Tags: lammps

I am preparing to conduct a shock simulation for an energetic material in LAMMPS with the help of a classical forcefield. How can I apply shock front absorbing boundary condition so that I can gather information during shock properly?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but have you got an answer from elsewhere over the last few months? Are you still actively in need of an answer to this particular question? Please update us!